# Self-referential join, multiple rows

Tags: sql

I have a tbl with:

```
| user | crs | status |
| usr1 | crs1 | stat1 |
| user1 | crs1 | stat2 |
| user2 | crs2 | stat1 |
```

How can I get:

```
user | crs1.status | crs2.status?
```

I'm trying:

```
select distinct
    mstr.[person username],
    abt.[module name],
    abt.[Lesson completion status],
    eoc.[module name],
    eoc.[Lesson completion status]
from 
    [aht16] as mstr
right join 
    [aht16] as abt on (mstr.[person username] = abt.[person username]   
                    and abt.[module name] = 'sdfsdfsdfsfd)'
                    and abt.[Lesson completion status]  = 'completed')
right join 
    [aht16] as EOC on (mstr.[person username] = EOC.[person username]   
                    and eoc.[module name] = 'sdfsdfsdfs'
                    and eoc.[Lesson completion status]  = 'completed')
where 
    mstr.[course title] = 'sdf'
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select user,
       max(case when crs = 'crs1' then status end) as crs1_status,
       max(case when crs = 'crs2' then status end) as crs2_status
from aht16 as mstr
group by user;
```

Note:  This uses the column names described to be in the table.  The query is using a different set of names.

Comment: sorry- crs names are very long.

Answer (score 0):

nice and easy- works!

i thought the self join would work, but it only made more rows.